# Java MySQL Connection failed

Tags: java, mysql, web, tomcat

I am trying to build a web application, which should be very simple. But I'm stuck at building a login site.

I've built a mysql database quizdb with the table users_db. When I run this code in a normal java project, everything works perfectly fine. But when I run it in a JavaEE Project with Tomcat 9 and MySQL 8.0.23- I get the exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The libraryy "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23" is included.

***validate.java***

```
package com.example.IUBHQuiz;

import java.sql.*;


public class validate {
    public static boolean checkUser(String email,String pass)
    {
        boolean st =false;
        try {

            //loading drivers for mysql
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

            //creating connection with the database
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizdb","root","1234");
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement("select * from quizdb.users_db where username=? and pass=?");
            ps.setString(1, email);
            ps.setString(2, pass);
            System.out.println(email + pass);
            ResultSet rs =ps.executeQuery();
            st = rs.next();

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return st;
    }

}
```

in the **pom.xml** I've added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Edit:
I'm using IntelliJ as the IDE and add the library through Project Settings -> Libraries -> + -> From Maven ->  [image: Screenshot of the project Tree]

And the promised **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>IUBHQuiz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>IUBHQuiz</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.0</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.23</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Thank you for helping me.
Janick

Comment: How do you deploy your application? Do you create a WAR with Maven? Can you add the `pom.xml` you use in your question ([edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66813091/edit) your question, don't post it as a comment).

Comment: _The library "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.23" is included_ - well, apparently it isn't (or it's the wrong one). You might want to give some details about how you think the library is included in the runtime environment (not just at build time through maven)

Comment: If you deploy using IntelliJ, try `mvn package` instead and deploy the WAR file that you'll find in your target directory manually. If that works, it's a problem with your IntelliJ configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've read a tip in another thread after lots of googling and it solved it.

The solution:
I also had to place the mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar file in the Tomcat/lib folder. Thats why it worked in a local java project and not on the server.

Thank you all for trying to help me.
Yours
Janick